# Altium PCB design

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, altium, eaglecad

I designed a schematic diagram to design a PCB. But when I want to update the PCB from the schematic, there are several errors. I can't determine the problem.

[image]

Comment: But why these are unknown pin?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have no footprint assoicated with your symbol. In this situation when you are trying to import changes from schematic to PCB editor Altium doesn't know where to place the nets because there is no footprint therefore there is unkown pin to connect.